Not sure why Proguard/R8 is removing certain code
We're adding R8 into our android app to remove some code from a specific dependency used by our app. Our proguard-rules file looks like below:
-dontobfuscate
-dontoptimize

-keep class !com.kaltura.tvplayer.offline.**, !com.kaltura.android.exoplayer2.scheduler.**, !com.kaltura.android.exoplayer2.offline.**, !com.kaltura.tvplayer.OfflineManager { *; }

-printusage usage.txt

After building our app and viewing the generated usage.txt file, we see that the code that we want removed from the dependency is removed. However, there is also other code that is removed and we're not sure why. That code is shown below:
kotlinx.coroutines.debug.AgentPremain$$InternalSyntheticLambda$1$677acd6fb4ca1651eb1c76ebe61d8c1a9f5aeadf35534bff63c38388e03cb9a0$0:
    public final void handle(sun.misc.Signal)
kotlinx.coroutines.debug.AgentPremain:
    public static synthetic void $r8$lambda$qtwhjy3HAlNEjQH7oAL6W8vp2zY(sun.misc.Signal)
com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox$$InternalSyntheticLambda$1$a66ca6c6de65b4f256ca2f0a8ce6032afe507a77d8c42ef3015c9db612807b7a$0
com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox:
    public static synthetic void $r8$lambda$hE-Ehj__sZakT88clijs-fYFgxg(com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox)
io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.jdk8.ObservableFlatMapStream$FlatMapStreamObserver$$InternalSyntheticApiModelOutline$1$87977bb73faf46839e24319ed6c7f5e872a83d3099d0adb8f3afc970e63deb06$2
io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.jdk8.ObservableFlatMapStream$FlatMapStreamObserver$$InternalSyntheticApiModelOutline$1$87977bb73faf46839e24319ed6c7f5e872a83d3099d0adb8f3afc970e63deb06$5
org.apache.commons.io.file.PathUtils$$InternalSyntheticApiModelOutline$1$778588db3304f74caa63c13b87cbf3c380b7de57d734f860afc58cfef4c8cf73$2
org.apache.commons.io.file.PathUtils$$InternalSyntheticApiModelOutline$1$778588db3304f74caa63c13b87cbf3c380b7de57d734f860afc58cfef4c8cf73$5
org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.EmptyFileFilter$$InternalSyntheticApiModelOutline$1$95abaa9ca0d4f21097e19aae95cd518500ff56bb37279c94168ab66f95dc3506$4
org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.EmptyFileFilter$$InternalSyntheticApiModelOutline$1$95abaa9ca0d4f21097e19aae95cd518500ff56bb37279c94168ab66f95dc3506$7

Even if we update the proguard-rules file to have a keep statement that encompasses all classes (like below), the usage.txt file still shows that the same code is being removed
-dontobfuscate
-dontoptimize

-keep class ** { *; }

-printusage usage.txt

We have tried a couple of different things to help with this issue.
First, as described above, we added a keep statement to keep all classes as a sanity check -keep class ** { *; } . We were surprised to find in our usage.txt file that the code was still being removed after adding this.
We also tried adding adding specific keep rules to make sure certain code was not removed (like below). These keep rules also had no impact on what code was being removed.
-keep class org.apache.commons.io.file.PathUtils** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.material.** { *; }
Does anyone have any insight into why this code might be getting removed and what we could add to our proguard rules file to prevent it from being removed?

From the proguard documentation:

-printusage
Specifies to list dead code of the input class files. The list is printed to the standard output or to the given file. For example, you can list the unused code of an application. Only applicable when shrinking.

This means that R8 prints the classes it would remove because they're considered dead code.
To verify whether code has actually landed in an app, open it in the Android Studio APK Analyzer and look for the classes.

Thanks for the reply. For the ones in the usage.txt posted in my original message, the ones that don't have "InternalSynthetic" in the name are removed by proguard. For the ones that do have "InternalSynthetic" they don't appear in the apk code regardless of if proguard is used or not. Do you know what they are and why they would be appearing in the usage.txt? I thought that if I add a keep statement like -keep class ** { *; }, proguard would consider all code in the app as a valid entry point and thus would not remove any code. However the usage.txt still has the code in my OP in this case.
